# How do I install openxcom from the ppa repository?

Tags: software-installation

I open terminal, type the lines listed on the website:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:knapsu/openxcom
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openxcom
```

and nothing happens.

Comment: I'm like 500% sure that `sudo apt-get install openxcom` should give some output. Edit your question and add what `sudo apt-get install openxcom` tells back.

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned by the author for 6 years.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to install openxcom in Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the below lines to it and save the file:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/knapsu/openxcom/ubuntu precise main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/knapsu/openxcom/ubuntu precise main
```

Update the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install openxcom:

```
sudo apt-get install openxcom
```

Comment: Notice that the builds for Precide are broken, but the package provided by that PPA are aviable for Quantal, Raring and Saucy https://launchpad.net/~knapsu/+archive/openxcom/+packages